# Comparação com compareTo e Sort

Tags: java

Boa tarde, estou iniciando em Java e estou com um probleminha.
Quero ordenar minha lista por ordem alfabética. Criei uma classe `Pessoa` e outra classe `TestaPessoa`.

Pessoa

```
public class Pessoa implements Comparable<Pessoa> {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private char sexo;

    public Pessoa(String nome,int idade, char sexo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public char getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(char sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }


    public int compareTo(Pessoa comparar) {
        int nomeComparar = this.getNome().compareTo(comparar.getNome());
        if(nomeComparar > 0)
            return -1;
        else if (nomeComparar < 0)
            return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

}
```

TestaPessoa

```
import java.util.*;


public class TestaPessoa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pessoa pessoa1 = new Pessoa("João Fernandes Ferreia", 46, 'M');
        Pessoa pessoa2 = new Pessoa("Fernanda Rodrigues Ferreia", 23, 'F');
        Pessoa pessoa3 = new Pessoa("Lionice Rodrigues Fernandes", 43, 'F');


        List<Pessoa> lista = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

        lista.add(pessoa1);
        lista.add(pessoa2);
        lista.add(pessoa3);

        Collections.sort(lista);

        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {   
            System.out.print(lista.get(i) + "\n");
        } 

    }
}
```

E o meu retorno está sendo:

```
Pessoa@17d10166
Pessoa@1b9e1916
Pessoa@ba8a1dc
```

Comment: ali você está pedindo pra imprimir o Objeto Pessoa, que utiliza o toString() pra imprimir o objeto. O toString() de um Object imprime por default seu endereço de memória. Sua solução é pedir para imprimir o nome no for ou sobrescrever o método toString() na classe Pessoa

Comment: Totalmente! Utilize o toString para este caso, que é um método que deve ser colocado na sua classe para gerar uma representacão textual do seu Objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque isso:

```
System.out.print(lista.get(i) + "\n");
```

Por isso:

```
System.out.print(lista.get(i).getNome() + "\n");
```

E arrume o seu método `compareTo()`, aonde você trocou o `<` com o `>`. Ficará assim:

```
    public int compareTo(Pessoa comparar) {
        int nomeComparar = this.getNome().compareTo(comparar.getNome());
        if(nomeComparar < 0)
            return -1;
        else if (nomeComparar > 0)
            return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
```

Ou se preferir, dá para simplificar ainda mais:

```
    public int compareTo(Pessoa comparar) {
        return this.getNome().compareTo(comparar.getNome());
    }
```

E por fim, você ainda pode simplificar o seu loop evitando ter que gerenciar contadores. Assim, ao invés disso:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {   
        System.out.print(lista.get(i).getNome() + "\n");
    }
```

Use isso:

```
    for (Pessoa p : lista) {   
        System.out.println(p.getNome());
    }
```

Comment: Obrigada! Agora apareceu os nomes, mas não em ordem alfabética.

Comment: @FernandaFerreira Resposta editada.